# Server File System Structure

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server, ftp, plesk, tree

I'm new to vservers, so maybe I have a basic misunderstanding of file system structure or SSH in general.

I want to navigate to my files, I have root access and my SSH terminal: root starts from Plesk shows as followed:

```
root@recursing-lamport:~# sudo du -shc /var/*
```

returns

```
16K     /var/backups
706M    /var/cache
504M    /var/lib
4.0K    /var/local
0       /var/lock
39M     /var/log
40K     /var/mail
84K     /var/named
4.0K    /var/opt
20K     /var/qmail
0       /var/run
1.6M    /var/spool
52K     /var/tmp
30M     /var/www
1.3G    total
```

So obviously, there are some files on my server, but if I use:

```
root@recursing-lamport:~# tree
```

I get:

```
    .
└── parallels
    ├── apache.inf3
    ├── billing.inf3
    ├── mysql.inf3
    ├── nginx.inf3
    ├── php52.inf3
    ├── php53.inf3
    ├── php54.inf3
    ├── php55.inf3
    ├── php56.inf3
    ├── php70.inf3
    ├── php71.inf3
    ├── php72.inf3
    ├── PHP73_17
    │   ├── php73-ubt20.04-x86_64.inf3
    │   └── release.inf3
    ├── php73.inf3
    ├── PHP74_17
    │   ├── php74-ubt20.04-x86_64.inf3
    │   └── release.inf3
    ├── php74.inf3
    ├── PHP80_17
    │   ├── php80-ubt20.04-x86_64.inf3
    │   └── release.inf3
    ├── php80.inf3
    ├── plesk.inf3
    ├── pmm.inf3
    ├── pool
    │   ├── PHP_7.1.33_98
    │   │   └── php71-ubt20.04-x86_64.inf3
    │   ├── PHP_7.2.34_151
    │   │   └── php72-ubt20.04-x86_64.inf3
    │   ├── PSA_18.0.34_5691
    │   │   └── release.inf3
    │   ├── PSA_18.0.35_6216
    │   │   └── release.inf3
    │   ├── PSA_18.0.36_6324
    │   │   └── release.inf3
    │   ├── PSA_18.0.37_6686
    │   │   └── release.inf3
    │   ├── PSA_18.0.38_7167
    │   │   └── release.inf3
    │   ├── PSA_18.0.39_7558
    │   │   └── release.inf3
    │   └── PSA_18.0.40_7609
    │       ├── examiners
    │       │   ├── congratulations.sh
    │       │   ├── disk_space_check.sh
    │       │   ├── panel_preupgrade_checker.php
    │       │   ├── php_launcher.sh
    │       │   ├── plesk_preupgrade_checker.log
    │       │   ├── py_launcher.sh
    │       │   ├── repository_check.sh
    │       │   └── sh_cmd.sh
    │       ├── plesk-18.0.40-ubt20.04-x86_64.inf3
    │       └── release.inf3
    ├── pp-sitebuilder.inf3
    ├── ppsmbe.inf3
    ├── products.inf3
    ├── report-update
    ├── setemplates.inf3
    ├── SITEBUILDER_18.0.29
    │   └── sitebuilder-18.0.29-deball-all.inf3
    ├── sitebuilder.inf3
    └── sso.inf3

16 directories, 49 files
```

I have no idea where these files are hiding, and how I can navigate to them and why tree doesn't show any of them.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You show two completely different paths. Are you asking why the files in those two paths are not the same? Probably, the reason is that they are different paths.

Comment: I don't unterstand, both are excuted in the main route after login. Is this not comparable like in windows if you start 'cmd' and you are at sth. like C:\programs\...

Answer (score 1):

Your first command shows the contents of the folder `/var/*`.

Your second command shows the contents of your current folder.

Evidently, they are not the same.

Comment: 'root@recursing-lamport' is this a path? At startup im in this 'directory' and tree as i understand shows all directorys expanded, but there is no 'var' folder.

Comment: Judging by the prompt, the second command shows the root user's home directory.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was that i've to go up too the root with

```
cd / or 
cd ..
```

and then with

```
tree
```

I see what I wanted to see.